# How to set the highchart and the table horizontally?

Tags: highcharts

This is what my highchart looks like atm

[image]

I kinda want the chart to be on the right side while the table to be on the left

this is my html:

```
<div id="words" style="width:70%;float:left;">
<table border="1" class="highchart" data-graph-container-before="1" data-graph-type="column">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Word</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>icon</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>text</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>your</td>
                    <td>9</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>post</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>document</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>with</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>parentNode</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>email</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>com&quot;</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>googletag</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What should i do to achieve such output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change HTML, then simply put table before Highcharts container and set proper styles (float, width). For example you can also use two divs: http://jsfiddle.net/68qdew8g/

```
<div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
  <table border="1" class="highchart" data-graph-container-before="1" data-graph-type="column">
      ...
  </table>
</div>
<div id="words" style="width:70%;float:left;"></div>
```